# unable to import function in django/python

Tags: python, django

I am writing a django project with follwing files:

```
ttam_container
    -utils.py
    -ttam
         -views.py
```

Codes within `utils.py` module:

```
def random_string():
    ...
def remove_blanks():
    ...


...other functions...
```

Codes within `views.py`:

```
from utils import *

def get_sequences(request):
      ...
    string = random_string()
      ...
    sequences = remove_blanks(sequences_with_blanks)
      ...
```

The error `global name remove_blanks' is not defined` is then reported. I thought I didn't import the `utils.py` correcty in the first place, but the `random_string`  works...

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Ensure that each package has a `__init__.py` file as well

Comment: i did have... didn't show it here

Answer (score 2):

The import should be:

```
from utils import remove_blanks
```

without .py

Comment: And also without the wildcard.  :)  +1

Comment: also, when i try to wrote it as `from utils import remove_blanks`, ImportError is reported

Answer (score 0):

The correct import would be:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from utils import random_string, remove_blanks
```

Modules must be in one of the directories in `sys.path`. This is initialized to the value of `$PYTHONPATH`, or some default if `$PYTHONPATH` is not set. For example:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 12 2010, 17:07:01)
[GCC 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-cyg
win', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/pytho
n2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages']
```

So if your module isn't in that path, you need to append the right path (`'..'` in this case) to `sys.path`.